# what is the highest order differential equation exist

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As far as I know that the highest order differential equation exist is the Biharmonic equation ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biharmonic_equation)).
can any one correct me if there is any higher order differential equation and what is the application of that equation.

thank you

**Update:** 
The  differential equation  has an application not just theoretically.

Comment: You can have a differential equation of any order $n$. Take $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f=0$ for example. Do you mean a differential equation coming from an application?

Comment: yes, differential equation coming from an application

Comment: This is not a math question. At best it is hard science, at worst it is historical. (I love history. I'm saying history is not *close* to math.)

Comment: This is not a math question!!??. not sure how to convince you that this is a math question if you consider PDEs as a history !!.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I mean, there's no limit to the order of the equation I can write down:

$$
\frac{d^{1000}}{dt^{1000}}y = 0
$$

is a $1000$th order differential equation. In terms of "what is the highest order differential equation *commonly* studied?" (or "what is the highest order *named* differential equation?") I think that's going to be a matter of opinion (but if you want to look through a list of named equations for fun, here you go: http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/eqindex/eqindex-pde.htm).

**Update** "Application" is somewhat subjective as well (application to what?). But here is an application of a $6$th order PDE: 
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-8659.2004.00762.x/abstract

A $9$th order PDE: http://shell.cas.usf.edu/~wma3/GaoM-AMC2010.pdf

Comment: actually I meant by exist is it has application not theoretically

Comment: ok, I found a $6$th and $9$th order PDE for you, though I'm not at all sure there aren't specific higher-order equations out there somewhere

Comment: Any application. physics, engineering, finance,...

 jut it has an application.

Answer (score 1):

Kaup–Kupershmidt equation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaup%E2%80%93Kupershmidt_equation has order 5.